# How do I embed fonts in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to provide a glass door maker an ai file to sandblast lettering on the glass. I need to provide them the fonts that I've used in Illustrator. They're regular fonts, don't need license. I can embed the fonts when I'm making PDF.

However, I cannot provide them a PDF file as they cannot use it in their CAD app to sandblast the glass.

How do I package fonts in Illustrator or package Illustrator file?

Thank you

Comment: I meant to say "embed fonts in Illustrator or package illustrator file" above.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. You can always fix typos with the [edit] button (or even that link I just typed)! If you want to know more, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] for way more info on how Stack Exchange and this site in particular work. Thanks for joining us and have fun!

Answer (score 4):

If they really need the fonts, you can give freely distributable fonts separately. I cannot imagine, why they want them, because you can supply ready to print Illustrator file where texts are converted to curves -  same as drawed ones. Select your textbox and goto Type > Create Outlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the fonts to outlines as @user287001 has described. There's no need to give them the fonts if you do that.

It's probably better at this stage to ask the company doing the sand blasting which format they would like. I would assume they probably want a vector file, but it's best to ask them to make sure.

If vector, there's AI (Illustrator's native file format), EPS, and you can export in SVG, and several CAD formats, which are available in Illustrator.